# World.QueryAABB giving incorrect results in libgdx

Tags: scala, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to implement mouse selection for my game. When I `QueryAABB` it looks like it's treating objects much larger than they really are.

[image: QueryAABB inaccuracy]

Here's what's going on in the image

1. The blue box is an actor containing a body that I'd like to select
2. The outline on the blue box is drawn by `Box2DDebugRenderer`
3. The mouse selects a region on the screen (white box), this is entirely graphical
4. The AABB is converted to meters and passed to `QueryAABB`
5. The callback was called for the blue box and turned it red
6. The green outline left behind is a separate body to check if my conversions were correct, this is **not** used for the actual selection process

It seems to be connected to my meter size, the larger it is, the more inaccurate the result is. At 1 meter = 1 pixel it works perfectly.

---

Meter conversions

```
val MetersToPixels = 160f
val PixelsToMeters = 1/MetersToPixels

def toMeters(n: Float) = n * PixelsToMeters
def toPixels(n: Float) = n * MetersToPixels
```

In the image I'm using `MetersToPixels = 160f` so the inaccuracy is more visible, but I really want `MetersToPixels = 16f`.

---

Relevant selection code

```
val x1 = selectPos.x
val y1 = selectPos.y
val x2 = getX
val y2 = getY + getHeight

val (l,r) =
  if (x2 < x1)
    (x2,x1)
  else
    (x1,x2)
val (b,t) =
  if (y2 < y1)
    (y2,y1)
  else
    (y1,y2)

world.QueryAABB(selectCallback, toMeters(l),toMeters(b), toMeters(r),toMeters(t))
```

This code is inside the `act` method of my `CursorActor` class. And `selectPos` represents the initial point where the use pressed down the left mouse button and `getX` and `getY` are `Actor` methods giving the current position. The next bit sorts them because they might be out of order. Then they are converted to meters because they are all in pixel units.

---

`selectCallback: QueryCallback`

```
override def reportFixture(fixture: Fixture): Boolean = {
  fixture.getBody.getUserData match {
    case selectable: Selectable =>
      selected += selectable
      true
    case _ => true
  }
}
```

`Selectable` is a trait that sets a boolean flag internally after the query which helps determines the color of the blue box. And `selected` is a `mutable.HashSet[Selectable]` defined inside of `CursorActor`.

---

Other things possibly worth noting

- I'm new to libgdx and box2d.
- The camera is scaled x2
- My `Box2DDebugRenderer` uses the camera's combined matrix multiplied by `MetersToPixels`

Answer (score 1):

From what I was able to gather, `QueryAABB` is naturally inaccurate for optimization. However, I've hit a roadblock with libgdx because it doesn't have any publicly visible function like `b2testOverlap` and from what I understand, there's no plan for there to be one any time soon.

I think my best solution would probably be to use [jbox2d](http://www.jbox2d.org/) and pretend that libgdx's physics implementation doesn't exist.

Or as noone suggested I could add it to libgdx myself.

**UPDATE**

I decided to go with a simple solution of gathering the vertices from the fixture's shape and using `com.badlogic.gdx.math.Intersector` against the vertices of the selection. It works I guess. I may stop using `QueryAABB` all together if I decide to switch to using a sensor for the select box.

Comment: @noone Not a bad idea.